# A blank screen is showing after creating invoice

Tags: php, vtiger

I am new to [Vtiger](https://www.vtiger.com). When I create an invoice it shows a blank screen rather than showing the added invoice. When I print `$return_id`
inside save.php after

```
$focus->save("Invoice");
$return_id = $focus->id;
echo $return_id;
```

nothing is printing. And when i try to `echo $this->id;` 
in "save_module" inside invoice.php its printing the id.

I have changed some codes inside `save.php` file for entering invoice two time and tried with die() inside `save.php` and `invoice.php` file. Now I Removed all the codes I have added. But still have the same problem

I couldn't find out the problem.

Comment: no error messages? Also check if your php is configured to show all errors: on php.ini `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Comment: @Jorge Campos its already on in my server